# Complicated Proof of Free Group Generators by $n$ elements implies $\operatorname{Rank}(F) \le n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

First I must point out the following corollary in my book:

> If $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group generated by $n$ elements, then every subgroup $H$ of $G$ may be generated by $m$ elements with $m \le n$.

Here is the problem I am working on:

> If $F$ is a finitely generated free abelian group generated by $n$ elements, $F$ has rank $m \le n$.

My question is, is the following are argument valid?

> Since $F$ is a subgroup of itself, and by hypothesis $F$ can be generated by $n$ elements, it follows that $F$ as a subgroup can be generated  Since any basis $X$ of $F$ by definition generates $F$, it follows that $X$ can contain no more than $m$ elements and therefore $rank ~(F) = |X| \le m \le n$.

I ask about its validity, because I found [this](http://www.auburn.edu/~huanghu/math7310/7310-hw3-answer.pdf) (first problem on the first page) seemingly unnecessarily complicated argument, and it has cast doubt on my own solution. Here is it:

> If $F$ is finitely generated by $n$ elements $x_1,...,x_n$. Let $X = \{x_1,...x_n \}$; let $i : X \to F$ denote the inclusion map; and let $F(X)$ denote the free abelian group on $X$ with morphism $\iota X \to F(X)$. Then by the property of free objects, there exists an abelian group homomorphism $p : F(X) \to F$ such that $p \circ \iota = i$. The assumption that $F$ is  generated by $X$ implies that $p$ is an epimorphism. Then $F(X)/ \ker p \simeq F$. If $F$ has rank $m$, then it has a basis $\{y_1,...,y_m\}$. Thus $F(X) = \ker p \oplus \langle p^{-1}(y_1),...,p^{-1}(y_m) \rangle$. The subgroup $\ker p$ of $F(X)$is also free abelian. Suppose that $\ker p$ has rank $r$. Then $n = r + m$, so $m \le n$.

So, is this proof unnecessarily complicated; is mine correct? Also, does this solution presuppose that a subgroup of a free group is free, or is there a way specifically to show that $\ker p$ is free? I ask because I don't believe it has yet been proven in my book that a subgroup of a free group is free.

**EDIT:**

So it appears that the solution presupposes that a subgroup of free abelian group is free abelian. Is there any proof that avoids this fact? Regarding the solution, why is it that $p : F(X) \to F$, the unique group homomorphism guaranteed to exist, is surjective? The solution says that it is due to the fact that $X$ generates $F$, but isn't this assuming something like $p(x_i) = x_i$ is true, which would allow us to say $p(\langle X \rangle) = \langle p(x_1),...,p(x_n) \rangle = \langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle = F$? I don't see why $p(x_i) = x_i$ is true, however.

Let $f : F(X) \to F$ be the homomorphic extension of $F(X) \ni x_i \mapsto x_i \in F$. In order to show that $p(x_i) = x_i$, it seems that I would need to show that $f$ satisfies $f \circ \iota = i$, as uniqueness would force $p=f$, but I don't see how to prove that $f \circ \iota = i$, particularly since I don't know how $\iota$ maps elements.

Comment: So you are assuming, that $F$ is free? Because it is not true, that $F$ fin. generated $\Rightarrow$ $F$ free.

Comment: @lush Yes. $F$ is also free. Let me edit the post.

Comment: I don't agree with your deduction: "Since any basis $X$ of $F$ [..] generates $F$, it follows that $X$..." -
How does $X$ generates $F$ imply that $|X| \leq m$? You can always "add" new generators to $X$ and it will still generate all of $F$.

Comment: When you say "free" you always mean "free abelian"?

Comment: @lush But that conclusion follows from the corollary I cited, right? The corollary says it can be generated by $m$ elements with $m \le n$. Adding elements to a linearly independent set would produce a linearly dependent set, right?

Comment: @57Jimmy Yes, that's right.

Comment: Every subgroup of a free group is free, and the same is true for free abelian groups, but both are not trivial results (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group#Subgroups) for the free abelian case).

Comment: Your proof is not enough. The problem is (and it is mentioned on the solution you link), that a generating set does not always contain a basis. So yes, there exists a generating set of $n$ elements, but you have to explain why there is also a basis of at most $n$ elements. You are mixing implications: a basis generates, but generators are not always a basis.

Comment: @57Jimmy I edited my post. Would you mind taking a look when you get a chance?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way around the fact that $\ker(p)$ is free. As for the other question: the composition $X \to F(X) \to F$ should be the same as the map $X \to F$, by the universal property. I don't know your definitions of free objects and so, but if there is a universal property involved, then there should be a uniqueness requirement somewhere.

Comment: In line with the issue of "free" versus "free abelian", I replaced the deceptive tag "free-groups" with the more descriptive "abelian-groups".

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for doing that, but you also deleted some of the text in the body of the post.

Comment: Oops, did I do that? Sorry, that was unintentional.